# Is there any option to Add sub users after Registration

Tags: category, customer, package

I have searched for what i want but didn't find anything helpful that's why posting this as a question.

I have digital products i.e Reports. To access those reports i have two options.

1- Purchase one report.
2- Subscribe to access multiple reports on the basis of the package.

Subscription packages will have something like, user(company admin) will select the categories for which he/she want to get access to view the reports. And option to create 5 or more sub users depending on the package. Each sub user can view the reports for the categories selected at the time of package purchase by company admin.

I am new to Magento. So i want to know is this something achievable in Magento. And if Yes, How ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No it is not out of the box.**

I think you want a second system beside the normal customers, let's call them accounts.

A customer can have as many accounts as they want.
An account can only access the reports, but not the invoices, change addresses, etc.

That way you have to check while logging in whether it is an account or not. Then you have only to implement a small account area.

Comment: Well i didn't get you properly as i am new to magento. What do you mean by Customer can have many accounts? I want that one customer(company admin) can create sub users to access reports and not anything else.

Comment: exactly that I proposed. But I recommend to NOT build a tree of customers.

Comment: its a built in feature of Magento or what? Is there any extension to achieve the solution you proposed?

Comment: No it is no built in feature and I don't know any extension which does this, but I'm quite sure, there exists one

Comment: just to correct myself, i am talking about this feature for frontend.